# Gitlab Account 2FA lost

Tags: gitlab, two-factor-authentication

I have lost my Phone and do not have the recovery code for my 2FA for GitLab.

So I am locked out of my account.
What are my options?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but the following, which I have tested only with gitlab.com free hosted accounts, may be useful for others with GitLab 2fa problems.

IF

- you have set up 2fa but then lost access to your 2fa device for some reason, and
- you have lost (or never saved) your recovery codes, **and**
- you had previously configured your ssh key in your gitlab.com account

THEN ...

You can create a brand new list of recovery codes via ssh:

```
ssh git@gitlab.com 2fa_recovery_codes
```

Answer the questions and save the list of recovery codes somewhere safe this time! I'm guilty of all of the above and this solution provided by GitLab is both simple and elegant.

Source: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/3765

Comment: Stack should have an option to throw as many upvotes as we can, when someone save's our lifes!

Comment: Worked like a charm , just make sure the SSH key has to be present on your account.

Comment: Terrific! You saved me!

Comment: This does not work for me. I got error "Two-factor authentication is not enabled for this user" but when I login I am still asked for codes

Comment: Man, you save my day. I reset my iPhone recently and forget the recovery which I saved before haha...

Comment: When I do this, gitlab does not accept the regenerated recovery keys

Comment: I lost my backpack, including my phone and laptop. Which means no ssh, recovery codes, or 2fa application. Is there any chance for me?

Comment: Tried pasting the entire thing before realizing this is a LIST of recovery codes, just take the first one if you generated them

Answer (score 2):

[nexus6](https://stackoverflow.com/users/839666/nexus6)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46010282/6309) also applies with GitLab Self managed, using [GitLab 15.9](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/02/22/gitlab-15-9-released/#more-control-over-your-ssh-connections-with-gitlab-sshd) (February 2023)

> ### More control over your SSH connections with gitlab-sshd
>
> `gitlab-sshd` is a standalone SSH server, written in Go, that provides more insight and control than OpenSSH.
> It’s lightweight and contains minimal external dependencies.
>
> If you host a self-managed instance, switching from OpenSSH to `gitlab-sshd` gives you
> metrics collection, detailed logging, and graceful shutdowns for SSH connections.
>
> Unlike OpenSSH, it supports the PROXY protocol and can pass on the original IP address
> when operated behind a proxy. This enables you to [restrict SSH access by IP address](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/access_and_permissions.html#restrict-group-access-by-ip-address)
> when your instance is operated behind a proxy.
>
> GitLab.com has used `gitlab-sshd` since 15.2,
> and 100% of the SSH traffic passes through `gitlab-sshd`.
>
> To learn more, read
> [this blog post](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2022/08/17/why-we-have-implemented-our-own-sshd-solution-on-gitlab-sass/).
> To understand how to enable it refer to [the documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/operations/gitlab_sshd.html).
>
> `gitlab-sshd` began as a community contribution from @lorenz.
> Thank you very much for your contribution!
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/operations/gitlab_sshd.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/5394).

This includes [generating new 2FA recovery codes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/gitlab_shell/features.html#generate-new-2fa-recovery-codes):

```bash
$ ssh git@<hostname> 2fa_recovery_codes

Are you sure you want to generate new two-factor recovery codes?
Any existing recovery codes you saved will be invalidated. (yes/no)
yes

Your two-factor authentication recovery codes are:
...
```